# empty string in dynamic SQL cause exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I need to use dynamic SQL in a store procedure. Here is my code

```
set @value = ''(empty string)

set @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #temp(ID) 
        SELECT distinct contact.ID FROM contact     
        LEFT JOIN address on address.ID = contact.ID'       
set @where = 'where ' + @parameter + '=' + @value  + 'OR ' + @parameter + ' = address.cityCode'

begin   
    set @all =  @SQL + @where 
    EXEC sp_executesql @all
end

when transaction begins, @parameter also has a value of ''(empty string).
```

exception throwed by JDBC:

```
Incorrect syntax near '='. at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.createException
```

I think it's caused by the value of empty string. So what can I do to make empty string valid when concatenating dynamic SQL? Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to happen if the string is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your empty string in quotes. Right now, it will work out to `WHERE parameter =OR` which is clearly bad syntax.

Change your code to include the quotes and it should work.

```
set @where = 'where ' + @parameter + ' = ''' + @value  + ''' OR ' + @parameter + ' = address.cityCode'
```

Note, of course, that you then won't want them in whatever you *do* set `@value` to be. So if you were accounting for the lack of quotes there, either remove it, or set your empty `@value` to `'''''` (a quote, two escaped quotes, then another quote).

Answer (score 0):

1. For standard application make, writing dynamic SQL inside of a stored procedure is just as bad as writing it in client code. SQL injecton and performance can still kill you.
2. In the context of your SQL statement, there is no value you can generically assign to `@parameter` that will make it work, `@parameter` takes the place of a column name (twice) in your SQL expression. What could possibly be a useful substitute? You might in theory test for @parameter and generate different SQL  for the lack of a parameter name (but you would have to know what alternative would be good in your case).
3. You will need to quote parameter if you use a "illegal" column name like embedded spaces or a SQL keyword.
4. You will also need to quote `@value` if if represents a string. In T-SQL you can also quote integer values, etc. without causing problems.
5. Did I mention don't use dynamic situation for an application like this even in a stored procedure.